# Is it possible to add data files to a ClickOnce project despite warning MSB3178?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, clickonce

Is it possible to add data files to a ClickOnce project despite warning MSB3178?

Hello everyone:

I am trying to deploy a C++/CLI application “App_real.exe” using ClickOnce Deployment under MSVS 2008. To do that, I have a C# launcher application “App_deploy.cs” that simply starts “App_real.exe”, as described in [that blog](http://www.michaelckennedy.net/blog/2008/08/26/ClickOnceDeploymentForUnmanagedCodeCVB6Etc.aspx).

When I build “App_deploy.cs”, I get “warning MSB3178: Assembly App_real.exe' is incorrectly specified as a file.” Apparently there is nothing to do about that warning, as people concluded in that [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/8aba52af-a1ba-4b1c-b745-8a18af7a3329/).
Now, my problem starts when I want to add data files to the ClickOnce project. As described in that [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fehc36e.aspx), I need to edit the manifest using MageUI.exe. When I add the data files and try to save the manifest, I get the same warning again “Warning MSB3178: Assembly 'App_real.exe' is incorrectly specified as a file.” When I publish the project, I cannot find the data files in the local ClickOnce directory “Local Settings > Apps > 2.0 >Data > …”

Hence my question: Is it possible to add data files to a ClickOnce project despite warning MSB3178?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you look in Application Files, what does it say for that exe file? Is it set to Include or Include(Required) ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. In the MSVS Solution Explorer, in the ClickOnce deployment project, the Properties of "App_real.exe" are: Build Action=Content; Copy to output directory=Copy always. Does this answer your inquiry?

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you mean. In the Publish Tab of the deployment project, in the Application Files, I find "App_real.exe" and "App_deploy.exe". Their "Publish Status" is "Include (Auto)" and "Download Group" is "(Required)".